# Sorting data frame properly

Tags: sorting

I have the following data frame (called finaldf) that looks like this. However the dates
are all out of order. How would i be able to sort this data to retain it all but make the dates be in order?

Comment: Welcome! Please, edit your question and add some code you struggle with, and add the tag for the language you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using python , and if its a pandas dataframe then
in order to sort data based on 'date' column you can use the following command:

```
finaldf = finaldf.sort_values(by="date")
```